# Syntax error in for-loop

Tags: python

The goal of my function is to collect the RGB colour numbers(1-255), find the average of the these three numbers and set all 3 of the RGB values to that average. I think I am close but something just isn't working and I'm not sure what it is.

Also, it says there is a syntax error on the first line of the function.

Thanks in advance

```
def grayScale(source):
    path = pickAFile()
    source = makePicture(path)
    height = getHeight(source)
    width = getWidth(source)
    sourceY = 0
    for y in range(0,height): # Note a colon here
        sourceX = 0
        for x in range(0,width): # And here
            r = getRed(getPixel(source, int(sourceX), int(sourceY)))
            g = getGreen(getPixel(source, int(sourceX), int(sourceY)))
            b = getBlue(getPixel(source, int(sourceX), int(sourceY)))
    average = (r + g + b) / 3
    newColor = makeColor(average,average,average)
    setColor(getPixel(target, targetX, targetY), newColor)
    print average       
    explore(target)
```

I've changed some things and this is the error i get now and i'm not sure why...

The error was:source
Name not found globally.
A local or global name could not be found. You need to define the function or variable before you try to use it in any way.

Comment: Can you post all of the code in question and the stack trace for the error?

Comment: Colons are missing and the indentation is off.

Comment: Add the colon at the end of the lines: `for y in range(0,height):` and `for x in range(0,width):` and make the indentation correct for the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with indentation and colons. Specifically, each `for` statement needs a colon at the end, just before the following indented block of code.

Also,  all code within a block needs to be at the same level of indentation. In your code, the last two lines are indented two extra characters. Here is the fixed code:

```
def grayScale(source):
    # Note indentation
    for y in range(0,height): # Note a colon here
        for x in range(0,width): # And here
            r = getPixel(getRed(source))
            g = getPixel(getGreen(source))
            b = getPixel(getBlue(source))
            average = (r + g + b) / 3
            newColor = makeColor(average,average,average)
            setColor = newColor

# Your code...
```

Make sure to read about [flow control in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html).